# What's the intuitive interpretation of quantum uncertainty $\Delta \hat{A}=\sqrt{\langle\hat{A}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{A}\rangle^2}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

As per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMFgfqRZYoc#t=38m34s), if $\hat{A}$ is a quantum operator, the uncertainty is given by

$$\Delta \hat{A}=\sqrt{\langle\hat{A}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{A}\rangle^2}$$

I understand what this expression means in a purely mathematical sense, but I have no physical intuition to it.

How should I interpret the terms $\langle\hat{A}^2\rangle$ and $\langle\hat{A}\rangle^2$, physically? And why, physically, should uncertainty be the square root of their difference?

Comment: Quantum mechanics is a little bit of a red-herring here. This is just the standard definition of standard deviation (which we often use as a measure of uncertainty in measurements), where $\langle \hat{A} \rangle$ is the average value of the physical observable associated with $\hat{A}$.

Comment: Once you accept that $\langle \cdot\rangle$ denotes an expectation value of a random variable in the ordinary sense of statistics, this is just the standard expression for [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). Do you know that, and so are effectively asking why $\langle \cdot\rangle$ is the expectation value, or does this already answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admittedly that expression is somewhat un-intuitive

$$ \Delta \hat{A}=\sqrt{\langle\hat{A}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{A}\rangle^2} $$

But you can rewrite the term below the square root in a mathematically equivalent way, and get

$$ \Delta \hat{A}=\sqrt{\left<(\hat{A}-\langle\hat{A}\rangle)^2\right>} $$

Now, here $(\hat{A}-\langle\hat{A}\rangle)$ is obviously an operator with mean value $0$,
and the whole expression is quite intuitively the standard deviation of $\hat{A}$.

Comment: Okay, I see the analogy with standard deviation, but since $\hat{A}$ is an *operator*, I don't see why that analogy should hold for operators in general. Can you justify the analogy?

Comment: @spraff It just follows from the definition of [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)#Operational_definition)
$\langle\hat{A}\rangle$.